# Kernel compilation options on gentoo with genkernel

Tags: kernel, gentoo

I use genkernel to compile kernel on gentoo. How do I choose kernel configuration. Gentoo Handbook http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/genkernel.xml says:

```
   Device Drivers --->
       Networking Support --->
           Ethernet (10 or 100Mbit)  --->
               [*] Ethernet (10 or 100Mbit)
               <*>   the driver for your network card
```

Where should I choose these options?

Answer (score 1):

Type `make menuconfig` in /usr/src/linux. That's where you can choose this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use genkernel:

```
# emerge -av hardened-sources
# emerge -av genkernel
# genkernel --menuconfig all
```

else:

```
# emerge -av hardened-sources
# cd /usr/src/linux
# make menuconfig
```